# Typescript object / Object - assignment issue

Tags: typescript

Why does assignment of a whole  object work, but reassignment of a property doesn't (unless you use the property name as an index)? Does this make any sense at all?

```
var m: object ;

m = { name: 'qwerty' };  // works


m.name = 'xyz'; // does not work

m["name"] = 'abc'; // works
```

---

Still, I do not get when to use `Object`, `object` or `{}`, since all three match only to objects without any properties - which are pretty useless. Whenever I want to match objects with unknown properties, I refer to `{ [x:string] any}` or `any`. So what is a practicable use case for these three?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this make any sense at all?

Yes, but there's several different type checking rules at play here.

`object` is basically a generic type that represents an object that has no known properties to the type checker. It allows you to assign any kind of object (non-primitive) to it with any kind of structure, because that's the point of it -- the similar `Object` and `{}` types also define no known properties, but allow primitives (like `string`) to be assigned, since `Object` is the base of all JS objects. `object` was added later as a means to express a *non-primitive object*. In any case (`object`, `Object`, or `{}`) when you try to access a specific property like `m.name` the type checker doesn't know what that is, so you get an error. The index based property assignment `m["name"]` has looser restrictions by default, even though the type checker still doesn't know what that is you don't get an error -- unless you turn on `noImplicitAny` then you do get an error on `m["name"]` saying:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.

This should point you in the right direction: if you want to describe an *object* with *unknown* properties of some type, you should define an [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html):

```
let m: { [key: string]: string; };

m = { name: 'qwerty' };  // works

m.name = 'xyz'; // works

m["name"] = 'abc'; // works
```

Answer (score 1):

All three assignments will work if `m`'s type is `{name: string}`, or `any`.

The `object` type is [relatively new](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type), and I'd say you'd benefit from a more specific type, for example to catch errors like `m.nmae = 'xyz'`.