# What is the {} type in interface?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm confused by these three types value in interface:

```
interface LK0 {
  name: {}
}
```

and

```
interface LK1 {
  name
}
```

and

```
interface LK2 {
  name: any
}
```

It seems that those three types are the same, as whichever type I specify to `lk`, typescript will compile without errors:

```
const lk0: LK0 = {
  name: {
    a: 1,
  },
}

const lk1: LK1 = {
  name: {
    a: 1,
  },
}

const lk2: LK2 = {
  name: {
    a: 1,
  },
}
```

So my question is: **What's the difference between these three types in interface?**

**UPDATE: 2018/12/27**

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793194/4340261) explain my question very clearly, about the difference between `object`, `Object`, and `{}` type.

Comment: I can specify `name` as a number or string or other value, like: `const lk0: LK0 = { name: 2 }`, typescript will still compile the code without error, I don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LK0` - type is `{}` which basically means an empty object. You will be allowed to assign any* value but any further code will see that property as having no methods - completely empty.

* if compiler option `strictNullChecks` is enabled this type will not allow `null/undefined` values.

`LK1` - type is *implicitly* `any`, see `LK2`;

`LK2` - type is `any` which means it can be any value and any further type inference cannot be made.